# Should I indicate that beryllium compounds exist in a device?

Tags: datasheet

Many years ago I built a power supply (an Elektor design) which used a 78HGKC voltage regulator. The data sheet explicitly said not to open the TO3 package as [beryllium oxide](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beryllium_oxide) (BeO) was used for thermal transfer.

Today I learnt that BeO ceramic can be used as an insulator in magnetrons in domestic microwave ovens, e.g. [YouTube: DIY How To Disassemble A Magnetron](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ADqfPOj3Rts).

[Beryllium copper alloy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beryllium_copper) is used in high-quality connectors for test equipment.

[Berylliosis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berylliosis) is currently incurable.

If I were to make something containing beryllium compounds, even though it does not come under RoHS regulations, should I only say so in the product datasheet, put a notice in the equipment, or just say nothing?

Comment: WEEE might be relevant in the EU, even if RoHS isn't.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In the EU beryllium was deliberately not included in the RoHS, however, there is/are suggestions which in words from a report says it best;

> Beryllium metal and beryllium oxide is not proposed to be restricted by inclusion in RoHS, however, the presence of beryllium containing parts in EEE above a certain concentration level should be labelled in order to ensure that these parts are dismantled and recycled adequately (cf. Section 6.2.2).

This is from "Study on Hazardous Substances in Electrical and Electronic Equipment, Not Regulated by the RoHS Directive" which was part of a contract from the EU. Available [here](https://www.google.ca/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=4&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwj0-JKYkLrNAhVB_GMKHXblDJwQFggvMAM&url=http%3A%2F%2Fec.europa.eu%2Fenvironment%2Fwaste%2Fweee%2Fpdf%2Fhazardous_substances_report.pdf&usg=AFQjCNFmq2m8rV-9dayJukuu1cWucp2tuw&bvm=bv.125221236,d.cGc).

EEE = Electrical and Electronic Equipment.

Comment: Thank you. It will take me some time to read all of that document.

Comment: @AndrewMorton From what I understand those are recommendations only and it's about disposal. If you like the answer accept it ...  ;)

Comment: does it mean that there would be a warning sign on microwave ovens if it contains a toxic amount of beryllium ? (It would implies that since there is so warning sign on the microwave they contains none or to few beryllium).

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer. As the beryllium compound is inside a TO-3 device, there is no need to declare it - the TO-3 case is welded and hermetically sealed. The only people likely to be affected by such a compound will be gung-ho students grinding the cap off the device or waste-disposal people grinding up electronics waste material. The students need proper supervision; the waste-disposal people need proper PPE.